# Constructor injection preventing custom resource processing

Tags: java, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

In my (non-trivial) Spring Boot 1.5.4 application with Spring Data REST and HATEOAS leveraging Spring websockets, I have some custom resource processors, some custom controllers, and some custom repositories. Sadly, when I use constructor injection in one particular Spring `@Service` class for a `MessageSendingOperations` dependency, my custom resource processors no longer get invoked. Reverting the constructor injection restores the execution of my custom resource processors, i.e. reverting from:

```
private final MessageSendingOperations<String> messageTemplate;

@Autowired
public ChannelHandler(MessageSendingOperations<String> messageTemplate) {
    this.messageTemplate = messageTemplate;
}
```

to:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSendingOperations<String> messageTemplate;
```

"re-enables" my custom resource processors which results in a `null` `messageTemplate`. So, there's a problem somewhere...but where??? Any ideas how to track this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making `messageTemplate` a lazily injected proxy?  For example:

```
public ChannelHandler(@Lazy MessageSendingOperations<String> messageTemplate) {
    this.messageTemplate = requireNonNull(messageTemplate, "messageTemplate");
}
```

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html):

> In addition to its role for component initialization, this annotation
>   may also be placed on injection points marked with Autowired or
>   Inject: In that context, it leads to the creation of a lazy-resolution
>   proxy for all affected dependencies, as an alternative to using
>   ObjectFactory or Provider.

This usually affects the initialization order of your beans, in this case allowing `ChannelHandler` to be initialized before `MessageSendingOperations`.  Without `@Lazy`, `MessageSendingOperations` will be initialized first.

Also: as of Spring 4.3, `@Autowired` is [no longer required](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3) for single argument constructors.

+1 for using constructor injection and `final` fields.

Comment: +1 -- I'd not tried that. Interestingly, `@Lazy` constructor initialization works, i.e., addresses both the NPE and it allows the resource processors to run...but why???

Comment: `@Lazy` causes Spring to create a CGLIB proxy which changes the order of bean initialization.  An easy way to see this is to set a breakpoint in the constructor above in your IDE, and observe the type of `messageTemplate`.

Comment: Yes; I'm wondering why `@Lazy` is necessary to make this work, i.e., it smells like a work-around for an, as yet, undetermined root cause...

Comment: It's difficult to reason about why without seeing source code, especially for `MessageSendingOperations` and `ChannelHandler`.